# QGIS - Setting out a grid of points within a predefined area and giving them specific lat/long values

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude, vector-grid

I'm basically re-learning GIS on the job, so forgive me for any inaccurate terminology or methodology etc. I will try to be as clear and concise as possible.

I will be collecting the lat/long values of 4 corners of a plot.

(With what little knowledge I already possess) I can make a line/polygon out of these points.

Then in QGIS, I need to be able to plot a grid within this line/polygon, with its intersects at even distances apart (For example a 6x6 grid would have 9 uniform intersections)

These intersect then need to become points of their own.

The end goal here being, a grid of points evenly spaced at, for example, 6m apart, within the original line/polygon

Lastly, I then want these points to have their own lat/long value so that I can put them back into the Trimble and find those exact points.

Comment: Can you clarify what your inputs are? Are they the 4 lat/long corners + the spacing of the grid eg 6m in your example. OR the 4 lat/long corners + the number of squares eg 6x6?

Comment: I dont understand "For example a 6x6 grid would have 9 uniform intersections". Can you add a drawing of what you want?